# Is there a way to get data on exchange-specific crypto prices using Yahoo finance?

Tags: exchanges, raw-data

Yahoo finance provides information on country specific cryptocurrency prices, but it seems they don't have information on particular exchange prices like coinbase for example. Is there a way to access this by using their site?